# access - subtração em consulta duplica valores

Tags: query, microsoft-access

Codifiquei as seguintes consultas:

SomaEntradasTotais:

```
SELECT artigos.Nome, Sum(Entradas.quantidade_ent) AS [Total Entradas] 
FROM artigos INNER JOIN Entradas ON artigos.Cod_artigo = Entradas.Cod_artigo
GROUP BY artigos.Nome;
```

SomaSaidasTotais:

```
SELECT Artigos.Nome, Sum(Saidas.quantidade_sai) AS [Total Saidas]
FROM Artigos INNER JOIN Saidas ON Artigos.Cod_artigo = Saidas.cod_artigo
GROUP BY Artigos.Nome;
```

StockTotal:

```
SELECT Artigos.cod_artigo, Artigos.Nome, Sum([SomaEntradasTotais]![Total Entradas]-[SomaSaidasTotais]![Total Saidas]) AS Stock
FROM Artigos, SomaEntradasTotais, SomaSaidasTotais
GROUP BY Artigos.cod_artigo, Artigos.Nome;
```

Quando a consulta **StockTotal** é executada contendo contendo apenas um registo de artigos, funciona normalmente.

EX: Artigo:a1 --> Entradas:10 --> Saidas:5 ------------> Resultado da Consulta: Artigo:a1 -->5

No entanto quando tenho 2 ou mais artigos ela soma os dois e duplica para as duas linhas

EX:

- Artigo:a1 --> Entradas:10 --> Saidas:5
- Artigo:a2 --> Entradas:20 --> Saidas:5
- Resultado da Consulta: Artigo:a1 --> 40, Artigo:a2 --> 40

Answer (score 0):

@demolion Para que os valores não dupliquem, é necessário realizar um `LEFT JOIN` entre a sua tabela de `Artigos` e as tabelas de `SomaEntradasTotais` e `SomaSaidasTotais`, conforme abaixo:

```
FROM (Artigos 
LEFT JOIN SomaEntradasTotais ON Artigos.Nome = SomaEntradasTotais.Nome) 
LEFT JOIN SomaSaidasTotais ON Artigos.Nome = SomaSaidasTotais.Nome
```

Também sugiro que altere a expressão do campo `Stock`, incluindo a função `Nz`:

```
Sum(Nz([SomaEntradasTotais]![Total Entradas],0)-Nz([SomaSaidasTotais]![Total Saidas],0)) AS Stock
```

A função `Nz` é utilizada nesse caso para retornar valor 0 (zero) quando o valor do campo for nulo.